# SQL query multiple tables in database

Tags: sql, database

I need to query 3 tables from a database. 
The table Client includes client id no. and client name.
The table Property includes property id no. and property name amongst other things.
The table clientsInterestedInProperties includes client id no. property id no. and date of visit to property.

I want to list the name of clients who have an interest in a specific property (with the name, not id. no) and the date they visited the property.

For example say the property is called Barker Hall, who is interested in it and when did they visit?

Can anyone help?

Comment: look up JOIN statement.

Comment: A http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be handy to show us what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use main filtering condition in your **from** table. So you must start with 
**select** ... **from Property** ...  ,
Then connect visitations to the property. It will generate different row for each visit, with
**LEFT JOIN** to get visitation to the property 
Then we need to get readably client names, not IDs, so we do 
**LEFT JOIN** to get client names 
And some additional filtering/conditions can be added with
**WHERE** clauses ( or INNER JOIN ) , like visiting period.

Example SQL for your case ( i don't know your table/column names )

```
 select PropertyName, ClientsInProp_VisitDate, ClientName 
 from Property
   left join ClientsInProp on ClientsInProp_Propertyid = Property_PropertyID
   left join Client on Client_Clientid = ClientsInProp_ClientId 
 where Proprty_Name = 'House 1' and ClientsInProp_VisitDate > '01.10.2013'
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an `IN` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM Client
WHERE ClientId IN
(SELECT ClientID  
 FROM clientsInterestedInProperties cip
 INNER JOIN Property p
   ON cip.PropertyID = p.PropertyID
 WHERE p.ProperyName = @propertyName)
```

Comment: Why you put your most filtering condition , filter on table property, **last** ? It's a big speed impact.